# Data queried by backend works fine, but can't give results to frontend, Java8 + Spring Boot 2.7.7

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

What should I do to fix it?

---

Exception

```bash
07-31 09:55:46.751 [127.0.0.1] [http-nio-8010-exec-2] ERROR c.x.f.w.e.GlobalExceptionHandler [handleException:72] - Type definition error: [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.LocalDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.xmkj.freamwork.web.page.PageUtils["rows"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.xmkj.tnlife.waterdispenser.vo.WaterDispenserVO["createTime"])
```

---

pom.xml

```xml
<!-- jackson-datatype-jsr310 --> 
<dependency>    
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>    
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

---

Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/waterDispenserList") 
@RequiresPermissions("manage:waterDispenser:waterDispenser") 
public PageUtils waterDispenserList(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> params) {    
    return waterDispenserService.waterDispenserList(params); 
}
```

---

Impl

```java
@Override 
public PageUtils waterDispenserList(Map<String, Object> params) {    
    Query query = new Query(params);    
    List<WaterDispenserVO> waterDispenserList = getWaterDispenserList(query);    
    int total = getWaterDispenserCount(query);    
    return new PageUtils(waterDispenserList, total); 
}
```

---

PageUtils

```java
@Data 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
public class PageUtils {     
    private List<?> rows;     
    private int total; 
}
```

---

front

```js
function load() {
    $('#waterDispenserTable').bootstrapTable({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${prefix}/waterDispenserList`,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        iconSize: 'outline',
        toolbar: '#exampleToolbar',
        striped: true,
        pagination: true,
        pageList: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
        pageSize: 10,
        pageNumber: 1,
        singleSelect: false,
        search: false,
        showRefresh: false,
        showColumns: false,
        sidePagination: 'server',
        cache: false,
        detailView: false,
        cardView: false,
        clickToSelect: true,
        queryParams: getQueryParams,
        columns: [
            {checkbox: true},
            {field: 'schoolName', title: '学校'},
            {field: 'dormitoryName', title: '宿舍楼栋'},
            {field: 'roomName', title: '宿舍号'},
            {field: 'imei', title: '设备编号'},
            {field: 'status', title: '状态', formatter: formatStatus},
            {field: 'peopleNum', title: '居住人数 <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {field: 'balance', title: '充值账户余额(元) <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {field: 'subsidy', title: '补贴账户余额(元) <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {field: 'totalWater', title: '总用水量(升) <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {field: 'createTime', title: '注册时间 <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {field: 'pcbVersion', title: '硬件版本 <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {field: 'softVersion', title: '程序版本 <i class="fa fa-sort"></i>', sortable: true},
            {title: '详情', field: 'id', align: 'center', formatter: formatDetailButton}
        ],
        responseHandler: res => {
            console.log(res);
            total = res.total;
            // 直接返回后端返回的数据对象
            return res;
        }
    });
}
```

---

The data queried by the back-end is returned to the List normally, and the dependency `jackson-datatype-jsr310` has been imported as required, but it doesn't work, and the error still occurs at runtime, so how can I solve it?Please help me.Thanks！

---

ignore：It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.（Only used to exclude community body constraints）

Answer (score -1):

OK，I fix it!
just do like this~

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    DateFormat dft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                // add this
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .setDateFormat(dft)
                .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8"))
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, true)
                .configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea as that disables the auto-configuration of Spring Boot and can lead to other surprising results (or maybe you already did something like this which disabled the `JavaTimeModule`).

Comment: If I don't want to disable automatic configuration, can I just write this directly to the yml configuration file?

Comment: You shouldn't need any of this. Spring Boot will automatically configure the `ObjectMapper` and detect the `JavaTimeModule`. Unless you have added `@EnableWebMvc` somewhere in your configuration which will also disable (even more) parts of the auto configuration.

Comment: In other words, can I restore the automatic configuration after deleting the previous configuration? Comment out `@Configuration` and `@Bean`.

Comment: Normally yes, if the auto configuration doesn't apply there is something else disabling this (like an `@EnableWebMvc` you (accidentily) added).

Comment: But I want to set `read-unknown-enum-values-as-null` to `true`,  is it possible to write it to the config file? Will it cause the auto configuration to fail?

Comment: You should be able to set this in your `application.properties` or `application.yaml`. For instance: `spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false`, `spring.jackson.deserialization.read-unknown-enum-values-as-null=true`.

Comment: Or, if really needed, create a bean that implements https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.11/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html.